# DB2 timestampdiff assumption of months

Tags: db2

I have query that get timestampdiff but from understanding of the function of timestampdiff that it have assumption of 30 days a month so my question is there a way to make it more accurate or way to make it more accurate to consider the timing in months that have less than 30 days or more than 30 days to get the accurate results, i been searching for information on this but wouldn't able to find any, any one got into that more.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the difference should be between `Feb 1st-March 1st` and `Feb 2nd-March 2nd` and `Feb 28st-March 31`?

Comment: May be you could use the DB2 native datetime arithmetics, just by subtracting one timestamp value from another? Unfortunately you didn't  explain what you're trying to accomplish, just some symptoms.

Comment: Sorry to not explain i simply get the timestampdiff between two time stamps in seconds there is no static value just data in two columns the thing that the timestampdiff might get time between two months that not 30 days so the results won't be accurate like Lashane said there is Jan 31 feb 28 and March 31 and may 31 and july 31 and august 31 and october 31 days and dec 31 so there lot of months more than 30 days so the results between two time stamps not in same months would not be accurate if it between two months one of them 31 days or 28 days is there way to accommodate it  accurate

Comment: The problem isn't actually `TIMESTAMPDIFF(...)`, although that function doesn't help any; really, it's due to the relative interval from the timestamp subtraction.  You can get an accurate number of _days_ between two dates (with some math based off the function `DAYS(...)`), but this may not be helpful.  What are you actually trying to do?  Note that if you're trying to display the results in some other application language, you may be better served by exporting the timestamp and using facilities in the other language - the math is non-trivial.

Comment: i have column called time taken which get the timestampdiff between two timestamps the only thing as i said that timestampdiff assume month 30 day so i was wondering if there way to make it more accurate to consider the months that have 31 days and feb that have 28 day